# Integral of measurable function defined on a discrete measure space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a discrete measure space. For simplicity we can assume that $f$ is non-negative. By definition we now that $$\int f d\mu = \sup\{ \int g d\mu : g\text{ is nonnegative and simple, }g \leq f \}$$
My intuition leads me to the conclusion that

$\displaystyle \int f d\mu= \sum_{w\in\Omega}f(w)\mu(w)$. I think this is a bit convincing since $\displaystyle f=\sum_{w\in\Omega}f(w)\mathbb{1}_w$ trivially. A non-negative simple function $g$ can then be a finite sum version of $f$ for a finite number of points in $\Omega$ and equal $0$ everywhere else. As more points of $\Omega$ are considered in the sum, $g$ approaches $f$ from below.

Comment: When you say "discrete measure space," do you mean $\Omega$ is countable?  Or just that singletons have positive measure?

Comment: $\Omega$ is countable

Comment: Yes, the formula is correct and it follows by just splitting $\Omega$ into singletons.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP's reasoning is totally correct.